# Why can't Design Automation find this specific part in my assembly?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

While running a modified version of the Autodesk Design Automation tutorial this error about a missing document keeps showing up. It only occurs when the iLogic rule within the document tries to change a parameter in this part.

I submit a workitem with some paramters. The plugin code changes the parameters one by one. Some parameter changes trigger iLogic rules to run. When iLogic tries to change a parameter in the part "Master Doppelstuetze.ipt" it throws the error shown below (see full Trace

Here is the line in the iLogic rule thats causing the error:

```
Parameter("Master Doppelstuetze.ipt", "Height") = Parameter("Height_iProp")
```

And here is the Run() method of the plugin that is executed:

```cs
  public void Run(Document doc)
  {
      try
      {
          var docDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(doc.FullFileName);
          var docPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(docDir, "Konfigurator.iam");
          doc.Close();
          // Activate own project
          DesignProject dp = m_server.DesignProjectManager.DesignProjects.AddExisting(System.IO.Path.Combine(docDir, "Main.ipj"));
          dp.Activate();
          LogTrace($ "Activating project file: {dp.FullFileName}");
          // load last active LOD to suppress/unsuppress components according to last saved state of file
          if (docPath.ToUpper().EndsWith(".IAM"))
          {
              FileManager fm = m_server.FileManager;
              string dvActRep = fm.GetLastActiveDesignViewRepresentation(docPath);
              LogTrace($ "LastActiveDesignViewRepresentation: {dvActRep}");
              //string lodActRep = fm.GetLastActiveLevelOfDetailRepresentation(docPath);
              //LogTrace($"LastActiveLevelOfDetailRepresentation: {lodActRep}");
              string modActRep = fm.GetLastActiveModelState(docPath);
              LogTrace($ "LastActiveModelState: {modActRep}");
              NameValueMap openOptions = m_server.TransientObjects.CreateNameValueMap();
              //openOptions.Add("LevelOfDetailRepresentation", lodActRep);
              openOptions.Add("ModelState", modActRep);
              openOptions.Add("DesignViewRepresentation", dvActRep);
              doc = m_server.Documents.OpenWithOptions(docPath, openOptions, false);
          }
          else
          {
              doc = m_server.Documents.Open(docPath, false);
          }
          LogTrace($ "Full document name: {doc.FullDocumentName}");
          // update parameters in the doc
          ChangeParameters(doc);
          // generate outputs
          // save output file
          var documentType = doc.DocumentType;
          if (documentType == DocumentTypeEnum.kAssemblyDocumentObject | documentType == DocumentTypeEnum.kPartDocumentObject)
          {
              // the name must be in sync with output localName in Activity
              var fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(docDir, "outputFile.stp");
              // save file as STEP
              // Some code left out here
          }
          else
          {
              LogTrace("Active document is not a part or an assembly. Saving of STP file unsuccessfull.");
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          LogTrace("Processing failed: {0}", e.ToString());
      }
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Change parameters in Inventor document.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="doc">The Inventor document.</param>
  /// <param name="json">JSON with changed parameters.</param>
  public void ChangeParameters(Document doc)
  {
      var theParams = GetParameters(doc);
      Dictionary < string, string > parameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Dictionary < string, string >> (System.IO.File.ReadAllText("params.json"));
      foreach(KeyValuePair < string, string > entry in parameters)
      {
          try
          {
              Parameter param = theParams[entry.Key];
              LogTrace("Trying to update parameter expression {0}... current value: {1}, new value: {2}", param.Name, param.Expression, entry.Value);
              param.Expression = entry.Value;
              LogTrace("Successfully updated parameter expression of {0} to {1}", param.Name, param.Expression);
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              LogTrace("Cannot update expression of {0}: {1}", entry.Key, e.Message);
              // If updating expression, try updating value instead
              try
              {
                  Parameter param = theParams[entry.Key];
                  LogTrace("Trying to update parameter value {0}... current value: {1}, new value: {2}", param.Name, param.Value, entry.Value);
                  param.Value = entry.Value;
                  LogTrace("Successfully updated parameter expression of {0} to {1}", param.Name, param.Value);
              }
              catch (Exception e2)
              {
                  LogTrace("Cannot update value of {0}: {1}", entry.Key, e2.Message);
              }
          }
      }
      var em = m_server.ErrorManager;
      LogTrace($ "Checking ErrorManager before problem");
      LogTrace($ "HasErrors = {em.HasErrors}");
      LogTrace($ "HasWarnings = {em.HasWarnings}");
      LogTrace($ "AllMessages = {em.AllMessages}");
      doc.Update2();
      LogTrace($ "Checking ErrorManager after problem");
      LogTrace($ "HasErrors = {em.HasErrors}");
      LogTrace($ "HasWarnings = {em.HasWarnings}");
      LogTrace($ "AllMessages = {em.AllMessages}");
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Get parameters for the document.
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>Parameters. Throws exception if parameters are not found.</returns>
  private static Parameters GetParameters(Document doc)
  {
      var docType = doc.DocumentType;
      switch (docType)
      {
          case DocumentTypeEnum.kAssemblyDocumentObject:
              var asm = doc as AssemblyDocument;
              return asm.ComponentDefinition.Parameters;
          case DocumentTypeEnum.kPartDocumentObject:
              var ipt = doc as PartDocument;
              return ipt.ComponentDefinition.Parameters;
          default:
              throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Unexpected document type ({0})", docType));
      }
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// This will appear on the Design Automation output
  /// </summary>
  private static void LogTrace(string format, params object[] args)
  {
      Trace.TraceInformation(format, args);
  }
```

I made changes to this tutorials code https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/design-automation/ according to this blog post https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/dealing-suppressed-components and a few others.

Any idea what the problem could be? I thought about model states, the project file, maybe the whitespace in the name. But I'm still fairly new to Design Automation and after a few days am kinda stumped.

The input is a flat ZIP file created through PacknGo. The ErrorManager does not show errors or warnings.

Please let me know if any more information is needed. And thanks in advance.

Here is the full workItemSpec:

```
{{
  "activityId": "eY0NRE3VLdYww7SuKwmVWdjE9bKjDpAi.UpdateIPTParamActivity+dev",
  "arguments": {
    "inputFile": {
      "localName": "file",
      "pathInZip": "Konfigurator.iam",
      "url": "https://cdn.us.oss.api.autodesk.com/com.autodesk.oss-persistent/us-east-1/9b/9a/f1/dab17a9c33a0f6b61d6226e64f7110d2f5/ey0nre3vldyww7sukwmvwdje9bkjdpai-designautomation-persistent?response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B+filename%3D%22SB50_Dev.zip%22&Expires=1680252856&Signature=MrC8C5A5ocmpo7G5Q6BqTbNGz3euA5nsCF-hEVgWHBGAUSsoHgWOkb713RKiAR-uhPtMe2322hxbL~s0K-~0bDUACDzGci-cIxH04JwyE6BdwRqnZMWaZm4RIGnYjZ6KqVh2IwqWh~DhNStBtdEO-zhTXUMNM7n2YW7qv-qd2~gBfDwd1WhwrlJ7RUFyLFrVsBajH2rbnbur7hS5AAonQZYTYkXyI2ipEe72EpLhR1YCiHbdQHL-V8nUNbpMfwGj55aOxBtn9gCmBgxy4BEzOGQAYQPCTFpq6WVI8GqbG7cBNd0ejMVZoRF3PyXidAl0eId3L1Rt0n5RVxq2Kmyfjw__&Key-Pair-Id=K5HRZD7MMO1U9"
    },
    "inputJson": {
      "url": "data:application/json, {'Bandlaenge_iProp':'4000','Bandbreite_iProp':'400','Motorwinkel_iProp':'44','Stuetztyp':'Einfachstuetze','Seitenfuehrungtyp':'Feste'}"
    },
    "outputFile": {
      "localName": "file/outputFile.stp",
      "url": "https://com-autodesk-oss-direct-upload.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/09/1b/3f/7d/bucket/ey0nre3vldyww7sukwmvwdje9bkjdpai-designautomation/signed-url-uploads/091b3f7d-b340-4c33-bd22-9838be1ae8c9?uploadId=XBmvrQPnF09EEIkqIcUmuUOnFjEnBH1J53m.fGMYjf0g1LtFCmXstf32p_tTwpV_dU8bmZeYINr755RXsnqZQda93tU88Kxwmc9TipdZlTgz26W.cV2WrAfFCca1TmpzAGNev9aO.QqvLsepBBCi2Q--&partNumber=1&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEK%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIFZ69Y2jBCD7TfMlWSz47%2Fnplu0%2BymjRwGlwfF0iXETaAiEAsiN33WjTTktaRGXEjm8Hb26w133qynYaiw71QbtD2bsqvQUIiP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAAGgw2MDQ3MzMwMDk0MDMiDI2EzCYbbPeHnCmnHSqRBT%2B7ilPDq5wEsDGuWA6u3E3D%2BGtBRwTMyealwgn1i5Ol3MuaZ%2FEN%2FOBU0Pj7nS0v2n9aOBkZpQlrSmW41GQX6lHJ3cq4TcLIhQNQQIEpFfAY9yN3uYCdjUzMJBhAmD83yMtqz0NUp37NmjZNVZQyc%2Fv89bBV8vOM53kjSQUlKRi5KqsESFrVWx%2F79LjcA%2FpXA%2BjLBBEiqE1ge8PbH1CtbCdxHmv2s%2BFB55qpaOEQTV4L%2BcqnR%2FpPYG1DKBj%2BISR5HcwaOcslTK17gu0%2FeIM4Ext%2FPWYw7h6fzklPqRc3yIiudvi295Bld9x9rJuUazHwFVzxJxDHn9OVOuGUo%2BK67VskjCNr2Yu3viKlOS3hLwsfWXIdxJ9w0F5Ihv3vPQYVxegmNI0iCzm%2Ft7xs20zKDQpBq1j4t2ibViJNRcL3mpN9%2Bavdf%2BLhdhfS%2FL2Ytn4RHQ4uaE9O%2FhpFnuEw5iDEtR2ACrQyrPxW4vIcTLfsw5lfRVW7jEuwOHXw6WYhXpZOUWhplSx0HBvMGqqrvaTMQ8E39zCfyLjAVfXFHIXWswuGMlXT9%2F3AL92QFtG7XTFGTSoegDTiOU0beI%2BjOhByG1Xu3NfykNDevxX7hHV5NwWn1jRNmQjoDmRh6SKoj2govstB4FQwT%2B%2FQMyhq1lG4ph2SNbGDu66S6HgWXuqOQ55%2BEMx4V8kbgXFXaMlJMQWSxsrAfrHAiSR%2FD3EUH1jPmAGhIRFrqRhvtad2yjQlS%2B%2FoPNJBd2HDjAUP0IJhV58b1DD4UCxo4toXlVoUvBeWFZ%2BY%2FSR8b%2BjK1hQiw%2FU15TCjZOa3rZYzNos33ETDJCOK5TNBty2BZrZfsn49LDTKt%2FyEaTqW4bZoc8G9DvZej%2FnHWDCpiZqhBjqxAeIdATY7MqpaVUPQHyWo3%2Fy3mpguA4V3B4kF%2F4QHrJlPOf%2Bsg4PCEljrNaJXih9RBHGesNpM0JlJUzhJbfko8S8hYDYetavue2rQlhCirXEKwpsfs%2By4%2BRty8FRReVSIzN05axDK1dGTZvgD29G7%2FvXzpJV5fsgFRhrZIYhR%2BOTPuDB8GXBfhpxt45rYKbQr1w3VtzEGyDJjMVhT27eTIBVEpTxdMLCqz5kQQEh34%2BjKNA%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230331T075416Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3599&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAYZTHFNX5QND6BXPA%2F20230331%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=708d5b7aded7781e15575e7197ba04c0718166f71c580ddc4d475b3c095cb3f9",
      "verb": "put"
    },
    "onComplete": {
      "url": "https://efd2-2003-d4-4f24-7400-cd37-a93-12ab-aa6a.eu.ngrok.io/api/aps/callback/designautomation?id=KD8w7KIo2hsdkFU-RRpg9w&outputFileName=20230331095416_output.stp",
      "verb": "post"
    }
  }
}}
```

And here is the full TraceLog:

```
Starting workitem...
Workitem started: 275a10e8683d47e08e435c684195b0f4
{
  "status": "failedInstructions",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/eY0NRE3VLdYww7SuKwmVWdjE9bKjDpAi/275a10e8683d47e08e435c684195b0f4/report.txt?X-Amz-Expires=90000&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjELD%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCTaMCRrYVMxQcDwUp6DPfcRdQTW7vb0xN1u1vQRq%2FhLgIhAJsba35wZl7pZWujEPcaLZQxuGPHS57qi7zuw2J8assVKokDCIj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQAxoMMjIwNDczMTUyMzEwIgx4uvQaoyXtZcJH0Xkq3QIcJVGy6aI42oF5bixWNEUXWBYHcqBl7mXZq4d7i%2FLNRkX22%2BDMRK4ZhtWSdHeUyLDMx7UfnfMlvTmxIl038%2FEDjTKwc%2FrnTAcGdp%2FGSRBjnsgJD8w9YS10zb2TtpUpx9OE5D%2FX7EXc1qL9KqDwO9M1NVrngI0Le0SSZKgWwYTVskpukH00yuCizLFyqr3OARMDbpb%2BChmnXuT1ucgkAVFHDAEd5ynMxMw%2BOLfqWk4F6VBepWo9YyqX5YPufsxTsdKDLz%2Buxi8JQXnIGvk0VRUSZx9ONeUKhrzZiOtxLbZD54VMKKwFjHsjl%2F4RB58VjKv7xseE4PjSUbFT2yUImcgKH6rv1FfWKmP1j0cW%2BycA6x6MxFAEcjLoFkioVldzS1fqDznWBtdXLC6LjSwT34j3GG%2F%2BJ4%2B5UA%2BzZR5Kdojb7pU5ggMXIH8NQDVt06fSyG4iC6KKmaAurD81xvH3MN%2BTmqEGOp0Bw0tB8JSJDGNqNAk%2F%2BKrVy791uet%2FkrVDVaUGYk%2BkkE%2FsdHznpXxgWgiLXbXHaisqtHE5p53GpEmZgxXT81PKUALP4cPwEcCBmI8Yea0yliHkdFrsW7bVB%2BWXeGe0tokmP8x7CG5R2fgvWJBp7Tw7%2BLlQnXKHpim7M78%2FF%2BiK%2BGXjqrU31QUoUHguCyUXO4h8a4Uwww0VqrTOO7Vy4g%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGVJZKM3CRU7VYHM/20230331/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230331T075816Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=2bbb29084c8db1a0a85b588e2fa2abbab2c2e157fbfbcd688585488bbf88abb4",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2023-03-31T07:58:16.9966627Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2023-03-31T07:58:17.222076Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2023-03-31T07:58:18.433261Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2023-03-31T07:58:34.295791Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 39765437
  },
  "id": "275a10e8683d47e08e435c684195b0f4"
}
[03/31/2023 07:58:17] Job information:
"CommandLine":[
  "$(engine.path)\\\\InventorCoreConsole.exe /doc \"$(args[inputFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[UpdateIPTParamAppBundle].path)\" /iLogicVerbosity Trace"
]
"Settings":{
  "script": {
    "value": ""
  }
}
"Id":"275a10e8683d47e08e435c684195b0f4"
"ActivityId":"eY0NRE3VLdYww7SuKwmVWdjE9bKjDpAi.UpdateIPTParamActivity+dev"
"Engine.Id":"Autodesk.Inventor_2023!28"
"Apps": [
"App.Id":"eY0NRE3VLdYww7SuKwmVWdjE9bKjDpAi.UpdateIPTParamAppBundle!1"
]
"BoundArguments":{
  "inputFile": {
    "zip": true,
    "localName": "file",
    "pathInZip": "Konfigurator.iam",
    "url": "https://cdn.us.oss.api.autodesk.com/Masked:L2/AKHbDkphZbeM6Gn5J7b57AGo=\"SB50_Dev.zip\"&Expires=1680253096&Signature=EdgmpbAUO8Ju0hr9gzvgMOqNDIyeNU5~8P3cVgqeM-zlc9aUg7RWLHSPTpEmpvO7qqIXFwBR89l96bql~s~jFT27ZxJ9vDQ1ZmoTdMRe3iHKs8La8kvalzNzD9MVvRkA90cdbNZXaac7i-8cVqVTT1DKfCW-g1SQWfTXUcsNb~q5zliTFFeswJeQuaADNPEMZJsArC5z5sis~szyq~0o1DXk8DUjOIRjSOk0BTEvA2EwU4eLrgGPn4IFeiLvb9GATK0xPFzfpgxuxPtlBCZnlNkNPpnTBPkiLqbfJbNS6YGKM0R3PNiogimqlff5UnQHEjjCW1v7xx-sSo7sonvpXg__&Key-Pair-Id=K5HRZD7MMO1U9"
  },
  "inputJson": {
    "localName": "params.json",
    "url": "data:application/json, {'Bandlaenge_iProp':'4000','Bandbreite_iProp':'400','Motorwinkel_iProp':'44','Stuetztyp':'Einfachstuetze','Seitenfuehrungtyp':'Feste'}"
  },
  "outputFile": {
    "localName": "file/outputFile.stp",
    "url": "https://com-autodesk-oss-direct-upload.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/Masked:dLAVrSb//AP5xb8aXYz7VE3ai80=",
    "verb": "put"
  },
  "onComplete": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "optional": true,
    "url": "https://efd2-2003-d4-4f24-7400-cd37-a93-12ab-aa6a.eu.ngrok.io/Masked:da3LsFX0Dt4Ru4Fpnx+LuTv7/gE=",
    "verb": "post"
  },
  "onProgress": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "url": "https://wlnr5sjl3a.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Masked:UK/Z3b5X3xUWxXiH6C9r9i9UlRU=",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-das-authorize": "awssigv4(us-east-1)",
      "x-ads-token-data": "{\"access_token\":{\"client_id\":\"eY0NRE3VLdYww7SuKwmVWdjE9bKjDpAi\"},\"scope\":\"code:all\",\"expires_in\":3550,\"client_id\":\"eY0NRE3VLdYww7SuKwmVWdjE9bKjDpAi\"}",
      "x-ads-gateway-secret": "Masked:F6VCvje5cIP0zOGCxgARjmSopQI="
    },
    "verb": "put"
  }
}
"Quotas":{
  "limitProcessingTimeSec": 900,
  "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 500
}
[03/31/2023 07:58:17] Starting work item 275a10e8683d47e08e435c684195b0f4
[03/31/2023 07:58:17] Start download phase.
[03/31/2023 07:58:17] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://cdn.us.oss.api.autodesk.com/com.autodesk.oss-persistent/us-east-1/9b/9a/f1/...'
[03/31/2023 07:58:17] Embedded resource [ {'Bandlaenge_iProp':'4000','Bandbreite_iProp':'400','Motorwinkel_iProp':'44','Stuetztyp':'Einfachstuetze','Seitenfuehrungtyp':'Feste'}] is saved as a file in 'Unicode' at: 'T:\Aces\Jobs\275a10e8683d47e08e435c684195b0f4\params.json'.
[03/31/2023 07:58:17] End downloading file. Source=https://cdn.us.oss.api.autodesk.com/com.autodesk.oss-persistent/us-east-1/9b/9a/f1/...,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\275a10e8683d47e08e435c684195b0f4\zip_2.zip,BytesDownloaded=39765302,Duration=497ms
[03/31/2023 07:58:18] T:\Aces\Jobs\275a10e8683d47e08e435c684195b0f4\zip_2.zip has been unpacked to folder T:\Aces\Jobs\275a10e8683d47e08e435c684195b0f4\file.
[03/31/2023 07:58:18] End download phase successfully.
[03/31/2023 07:58:18] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[03/31/2023 07:58:18] Command line: [ /doc "T:\Aces\Jobs\275a10e8683d47e08e435c684195b0f4\file\Konfigurator.iam" /al "T:\Aces\Applications\1fec54fda2691b930bc62b7c406c8b7c.eY0NRE3VLdYww7SuKwmVWdjE9bKjDpAi.UpdateIPTParamAppBundle[1].package" /iLogicVerbosity Trace]
[03/31/2023 07:58:18] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[03/31/2023 07:58:18] Start script phase.
[03/31/2023 07:58:18] Start Inventor Core Engine standard output dump.
[03/31/2023 07:58:18] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : InventorCoreConsole.exe: 25.0.18300.0, 498-7e5d2c9
[03/31/2023 07:58:18] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Starting Inventor Server.
[03/31/2023 07:58:18] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Trying to get Inventor Server version in use.
[03/31/2023 07:58:18] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Inventor Server version is 27, 10, 20801, 0000.
[03/31/2023 07:58:20] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Started Inventor Server 2023.1 (Build 271208000, 208) (27, 10, 20801, 0000)
[03/31/2023 07:58:20] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Loading plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[03/31/2023 07:58:20]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Activating plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[03/31/2023 07:58:20]     iLogic Plugin: initializing...
[03/31/2023 07:58:20] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Loading plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[03/31/2023 07:58:20] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting up iLogicLogLevelTo: Trace
[03/31/2023 07:58:20] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Getting Inventor plug-in.
[03/31/2023 07:58:20] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Plug-in: UpdateIPTParam
[03/31/2023 07:58:20]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Activating plug-in: UpdateIPTParam
[03/31/2023 07:58:20]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : : UpdateIPTParam (1.0.0.0): initializing... 
[03/31/2023 07:58:20]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Executing 'RunWithArguments' method on Automation object.
[03/31/2023 07:58:21]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Activating project file: T:\Aces\Jobs\275a10e8683d47e08e435c684195b0f4\file\SB50.ipj
[03/31/2023 07:58:21]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : LastActiveDesignViewRepresentation: Ansicht1
[03/31/2023 07:58:21]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : LastActiveModelState: iLogic
[03/31/2023 07:58:23]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Full document name: T:\Aces\Jobs\275a10e8683d47e08e435c684195b0f4\file\Konfigurator.iam
[03/31/2023 07:58:23]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Trying to update parameter expression Bandlaenge_iProp... current value: 1800 mm, new value: 4000
[03/31/2023 07:58:25] [iLogic]INFO| 1: >>---------------------------
[03/31/2023 07:58:25] [iLogic]TRACE|Entering rule: iProp_to_Master (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:25] [iLogic]TRACE|Trigger: Bandlaenge_iProp (Konfigurator.iam) = 4000 mm
[03/31/2023 07:58:25] [iLogic]TRACE|Exiting rule: iProp_to_Master (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:25] [iLogic]TRACE|Entering rule: Grenzen (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:25] [iLogic]TRACE|Trigger: Bandlaenge (Konfigurator.iam) = 4000 mm
[03/31/2023 07:58:26] [iLogic]TRACE|Exiting rule: Grenzen (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:26] [iLogic]TRACE|Entering rule: Stuetzen_Anzahl (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:26] [iLogic]TRACE|Trigger: Bandlaenge (Konfigurator.iam) = 4000 mm
[03/31/2023 07:58:27] [iLogic]TRACE|Exiting rule: Stuetzen_Anzahl (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:27] [iLogic]TRACE|Entering rule: Stuetze_und_Halter (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:27] [iLogic]TRACE|Trigger: Bandlaenge (Konfigurator.iam) = 4000 mm
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Exiting rule: Stuetze_und_Halter (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Successfully updated parameter expression of Bandlaenge_iProp to 4000 mm
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Trying to update parameter expression Bandbreite_iProp... current value: 400 mm, new value: 400
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Successfully updated parameter expression of Bandbreite_iProp to 400 mm
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Trying to update parameter expression Motorwinkel_iProp... current value: 90 deg, new value: 44
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]INFO| 2: >>---------------------------
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Entering rule: iProp_to_Master (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Trigger: Motorwinkel_iProp (Konfigurator.iam) = 44 deg
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Exiting rule: iProp_to_Master (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Entering rule: Grenzen (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Trigger: Motorwinkel (Konfigurator.iam) = 44 deg
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Exiting rule: Grenzen (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Entering rule: Stuetzen_Anzahl (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Trigger: Motorwinkel (Konfigurator.iam) = 44 deg
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Exiting rule: Stuetzen_Anzahl (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Entering rule: Stuetze_und_Halter (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Trigger: Motorwinkel (Konfigurator.iam) = 44 deg
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Exiting rule: Stuetze_und_Halter (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Successfully updated parameter expression of Motorwinkel_iProp to 44 deg
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Trying to update parameter expression Stuetztyp... current value: "Keine", new value: Einfachstuetze
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Cannot update expression of Stuetztyp: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Trying to update parameter value Stuetztyp... current value: Keine, new value: Einfachstuetze
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]INFO| 3: >>---------------------------
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Entering rule: iProp_to_Master (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Trigger: Stuetztyp (Konfigurator.iam) = Einfachstuetze
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Exiting rule: iProp_to_Master (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Successfully updated parameter expression of Stuetztyp to Einfachstuetze
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Trying to update parameter expression Seitenfuehrungtyp... current value: "Keine", new value: Feste
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Cannot update expression of Seitenfuehrungtyp: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Trying to update parameter value Seitenfuehrungtyp... current value: Keine, new value: Feste
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]INFO| 4: >>---------------------------
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Entering rule: iProp_to_Master (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Trigger: Seitenfuehrungtyp (Konfigurator.iam) = Feste
[03/31/2023 07:58:28] [iLogic]TRACE|Exiting rule: iProp_to_Master (in Konfigurator.iam)
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Successfully updated parameter expression of Seitenfuehrungtyp to Feste
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking ErrorManager before problem
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HasErrors = False
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HasWarnings = False
[03/31/2023 07:58:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : AllMessages = 
[03/31/2023 07:58:29]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking ErrorManager after problem
[03/31/2023 07:58:29]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HasErrors = False
[03/31/2023 07:58:29]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HasWarnings = False
[03/31/2023 07:58:29]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : AllMessages = 
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Output file saved successfully as T:\Aces\Jobs\275a10e8683d47e08e435c684195b0f4\file\outputFile.stp
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Performing iLogic diagnostics...
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : iLogic error 
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]  Context: RuleRunning 
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]  Details: System.ArgumentException: Parameter: The document named "Master Doppelstuetze.ipt" was not found.
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]    at iLogic.ParamDynamicFinder.ThrowException(String callerName)
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]    at ThisRule.Syskomp()
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]    at ThisRule.Main()
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]    at Autodesk.iLogic.Exec.AppDomExec.ExecRuleInAssembly(Assembly assem)
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]    at iLogic.RuleEvalContainer.ExecRuleEval(String execRule)
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : iLogic error 
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]  Context: RuleRunning 
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]  Details: System.ArgumentException: Parameter: The document named "Master Doppelstuetze.ipt" was not found.
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]    at iLogic.ParamDynamicFinder.ThrowException(String callerName)
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]    at ThisRule.Syskomp()
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]    at ThisRule.Main()
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]    at Autodesk.iLogic.Exec.AppDomExec.ExecRuleInAssembly(Assembly assem)
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]    at iLogic.RuleEvalContainer.ExecRuleEval(String execRule)
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : End of iLogic diagnostics...
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Deactivating plug-in: UpdateIPTParam
[03/31/2023 07:58:32]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : : UpdateIPTParam: deactivating... 
[03/31/2023 07:58:33] Processing failed
[03/31/2023 07:58:34] End Inventor Core Engine standard output dump.
[03/31/2023 07:58:34] Error: Application InventorCoreConsole.exe exits with code -1 which indicates an error.
[03/31/2023 07:58:34] End script phase.
[03/31/2023 07:58:34] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[03/31/2023 07:58:34] Job finished with result FailedExecution
[03/31/2023 07:58:34] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedInstructions",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/...",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2023-03-31T07:58:16.9966627Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2023-03-31T07:58:17.222076Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2023-03-31T07:58:18.433261Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2023-03-31T07:58:34.295791Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 39765437
  },
  "id": "275a10e8683d47e08e435c684195b0f4"
}
```

I left out the full URLs to save on space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a note that you do not need it use the `/i` command line argument if you want to open the document programmatically, because you first want to activate a specific Inventor project.
You could have e.g. this command line `$(engine.path)\\InventorCoreConsole.exe /doc "$(args[inputFile].path)" /al "$(appbundles[{0}].path)" /iLogicVerbosity Trace` then retrieve the full document path from `doc`: 
As you can see I added `/iLogicVerbosity Trace` to get more info in the report about what iLogic was doing.

```
public void RunWithArguments(Document doc, NameValueMap map)
{
    try
    {
        // you need the 'Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Inventor.Utils' nuget package for this
        var fullDocName = map.AsString("doc"); 
// ...
```

I could not reproduce the issue with my sample project:
https://aps-design-automation-nodejs-asm.adamenagy.repl.co/ 
Sample assembly: https://github.com/adamenagy/Container/blob/master/PackAndGo.zip 
Space character in part file's name does not seem to be an issue.

Other replit projects that can be forked:
https://replit.com/@AdamENagy

You can ignore providing Height and Width in the UI - the **work item** params are hardcoded for the sample assembly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Adam. I changed my command line as you suggested, but it did not fix the error. Can you tell me what the Config argument in the inputJson is for? I added my complete workItemSpec and the full TraceLog to the original question. It's very possible I'm just not doing something correctly in the Design Automation context. Like I said, changing the same pamaeters on Desktop Inventor works fine.

Comment: "Config" is the name of the parameter in the sample assembly I provided that I'm changing, which triggers a rule that changes a parameter in the referenced part file using the `Parameter("Quader part.ipt", "Length")` syntax that you are using as well

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. Does the additional information give you any ideas? Note: I mixed up some names in my original post, but now everything is exactly as it is in my code and the log.

Comment: I wonder if perhaps it's some character set issue in the zip?
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/special-characters-file-names
You can try this to make sure that all files got unzipped correctly: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/using-argument-adskdebug-troubleshot-failure-job-design-automation

Comment: Thanks a ton Adam. It was a problem with the special characters. Even though the file that caused the error was fine, a few others were not. Zipping the input folder with 7-Zip while using the "cu" parameters solved the problem.